# Where to see the logs of Azure Function App

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-function-app

I have written a small code in azure function app using nodejs to connect with snowflake. Here is my code

```
context.log("starting connection");
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
// Create a Connection object that we can use later to connect.
context.log("prep conn");
var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
    account: "macc_name",
    username: "usr",
    password: "psswd",
    database: "TEST",
    schema: "schema"
    }
    );
console.log("making conn");
connection.connect( 
    function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            context.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
            } 
        else {
            context.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
            // Optional: store the connection ID.
            connection_ID = conn.getId();
            context.log("COnnection id is : " + connection_ID)
            }
        }
    )
```

But when I go to monitor tab of function I only see below logs

```
starting connection
prep conn
making conn
```

But I am not able to see these logs..

```
Successfully connected to Snowflake.
COnnection id is : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any Idea where I can see those logs as well because I am not getting any info regarding my snowflake connection status. The Azure function is completing with status code 200.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Kudu Console ?

From the menu, select **`Debug console > CMD`**

Go into **`LogFiles > Application > Functions > Function > [Name of your function]`**

`https://[your-function-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/` There you will see a list of log files.

Comment: Here also only those context logs are available which were there in monitor tabs

Comment: Then you need to write custom logs using app insights